# PDO returning a single row while MySQL returns multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, max

I have the following table in my database:

```
    id    |    reference    |    secondID    
---------------------------------------------
    1     |        11       |      1
    2     |        12       |      1
    3     |        12       |      2
    4     |        13       |      1
    5     |        13       |      2
    6     |        13       |      3
```

And I want to get the max secondID for each reference, so I'm doing the next SQL query:

```
SELECT *, MAX(secondID) FROM TABLE_A WHERE 1 GROUP BY REFERENCE
```

If i do this query directly into database through phpMyAdmin I get what I expected:

```
    id    |    reference    |    secondID    
---------------------------------------------
    1     |        11       |      1
    3     |        12       |      2
    6     |        13       |      3
```

The problem is that I don't get the same result when doing this in PHP since I only get one row returned insted of three

(here's some code for the query)

```
$sql = "SELECT *, MAX(secondID) FROM TABLE_A WHERE 1 GROUP BY REFERENCE";
$this->result = $this->db->prepare($sql);

$confirmation = $this->result->execute();

if ($this->result->errorCode() != 0)
{
    $errors = $this->result->errorInfo();
    print_r($errors);
}

if ($confirmation)
{
    return $this->result;
}

return $confirmation;
```

(and here how I get the data)

```
$row_number = 0;
while ($data = $db_resource->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo $row_number . '<br />';
    $row_number++;
}
```

I know that if I get rid of 'MAX' and 'GROUP BY' I get more than one row in PHP but I don't understand why this is happening with those statements.

Any advice I could take?

**SOLUTION**
After some code revision on my part I found that while **the SQL query I print to debug code is correct** and works as expected it **doesn't occur in PHP due to a bad assign order on bindValue()** instructions that for some reason gets unnoticed.

I haven't put that code in the question for clarity sake and because is a heavy chunk of code, so sorry for losing everyones time on that question and thanks to responses.

Comment: What is `$this->resultado`?  A typo?

Comment: I don't quite get how $data, $db_resource and $confirmation tie together. Maybe that is the problem?

Comment: Yeah, $this->result is a typo for my part, I'll edit the question.
For $db_resource->fetchAll I still get only one row.

And for the question about $db_resource and $confirmation, the first code is in a class that gets a query and returns the object after doing execute().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some code revision on my part I found that while **the SQL query I print to debug code is correct** and works as expected it **doesn't occur in PHP due to a bad assign order on bindValue()** instructions that for some reason gets unnoticed.

I haven't put that code in the question for clarity sake and because is a heavy chunk of code, so sorry for losing everyones time on that question and thanks to responses.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  reference, MAX(secondID) MAX_ID
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP   BY reference
        ) b ON a.reference = b.reference AND
                a.secondID = b.MAX_ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/697ff/1)

or

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
WHERE   a.secondID = 
        (
            SELECT  MAX(secondID)
            FROM    tableName b
            WHERE   b.REFERENCE = a.REFERENCE
        )
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/697ff/2)

OUTPUT

```
╔════╦═══════════╦══════════╗
║ ID ║ REFERENCE ║ SECONDID ║
╠════╬═══════════╬══════════╣
║  1 ║        11 ║        1 ║
║  3 ║        12 ║        2 ║
║  6 ║        13 ║        3 ║
╚════╩═══════════╩══════════╝
```

Comment: Yes, this is the correct way to obtain the groupwise maximum (and therefore the `ID` of each group's maximum record); but it completely fails to address the actual problem faced by the OP.